# Laravel - Migrate database on package register

Tags: php, database, laravel, package

I'm creating a laravel package and want to run a migration file in the service provider `register` method. 
In other laravel packages I want to add entries to the new database table, which should also be handled in the `register` method.

The database is created before running `composer install`.

1. How can I run the migration in the `register` method?
2. How can I create an entry for the new database table from an other laravel package within the `register` method?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'create an entry for new table  from another package'?

Comment: For example in the first package I create a settings migration and model. In an other package I want to add a new entry to settings within the register method of the service provider, so that the settings are automatically added after installing the package.

Answer (score 1):

You can [register](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/packages) migrations with this command:

```
$this->publishes([
        __DIR__.'/../database/migrations/' => database_path('migrations')
    ], 'migrations');
```

After installing your package, user should run `php artisan vendor:publish` command to publish configs, migrations, commands etc.

Then you can try to [call commands your a code](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#calling-commands-via-code):

```
Artisan::call('vendor:publish');
```

Comment: Yes I know but I want to skip the steps to publish the migrations. Want to run the migration directly after installing the package

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea, but you could try commands from register method: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#calling-commands-via-code

Comment: I think the artisan call should work in a normal setup but I work with docker and there it is a bit more complicated. After discussing with issue with my teammate we switch from database migration to a config file where other packages can append to. But thanks for your help